# cpp thread join if two threads rely each other should using join cause deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
std::mutex lock_bar_;

std::mutex lock_foo_;
int n = 3;

void foo() {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        lock_foo_.lock();
        // printFoo() outputs "foo". Do not change or remove this line.
        std::cout << "1\n";
        lock_bar_.unlock();
    }
}

void bar() {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        lock_bar_.lock();
        // printBar() outputs "bar". Do not change or remove this line.
        std::cout << "2\n";
        lock_foo_.unlock();
    }
}

int main(){
    lock_bar_.lock();
    std::thread t1{foo};
    std::thread t2{bar};

    t1.join();            // line 1
    std::cout << "333\n"; // line 2
    t2.join();            // line 3
    std::cout << "3\n";   // line 4
}
```

the result is

```
1
2
1
2
1
2
333
3
```

or

```
1
2
1
2
1
333
2
3
```

my question is : why this programs can run without deadlock?

how join() is actually working?

when program executes line 1, according to cppreference *https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join*

"Blocks the current thread until the thread identified by *this finishes its execution."

My understanding is that the main thead should stop. It waits until thread t1 is finsihed. then execute line 2 and the rest.
but program seems like that it executes line 1 and line 3. when thread t1 is finshed, it runs line 2. when thread t2 is finished, it executes line 4.
I am confused about join().

if anyone can help, much appreciated

***first edited:***

ignore original program

new program is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

int n = 10;
bool first = true;
std::condition_variable cv1;
std::condition_variable cv2;
std::mutex m;



void foo() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m, std::defer_lock);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ul.lock();
        cv1.wait(ul, [&]()->bool {return first;} );
        std::cout << "1\n";
        // printFoo() outputs "foo". Do not change or remove this line.
        first = !first;
        ul.unlock();
        cv2.notify_all();
    }
}

void bar() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m, std::defer_lock);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ul.lock();
        cv2.wait(ul, [&]()->bool {return !first;} );
        // printBar() outputs "bar". Do not change or remove this line.
        std::cout << "2\n";
        first = !first;
        ul.unlock();
        cv1.notify_all();
    }
}

int main(){
    std::thread t1{foo};
    std::thread t2{bar};

    t1.join();
    std::cout << "3\n";
    t2.join();
}
```

same questions

Comment: how program knows it immedately executes line 1 and line 3, but delay line 2 and line4

Comment: When you try to run two threads in lockstep, you probably shouldn't be using threads at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your threads do very little work. Depending on your os and number of cpu cores, threads will only switch at a fixed interval. There is a reasonable chance that after `t1.join` returns `t2` has already finished executing (your first output).

If you add some sleeps to the loops in your threads you should see your second output every time as `t2` will still be executing when `t1.join` returns.

Note that unlocking a mutex from a thread that didn't originally lock the mutex has undefined behaviour: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock

Comment: thank you for your answer, please see the edited program.

Comment: Your new code is essentially doing the same thing but in a different way, the result is the same

Comment: my question is about how join() works, because thread t1 and t2 rely each other, when executing t1.join(), the main threads should just pause and waiting t1 finished, but actually, it executes t2 still. why does that happen.

Comment: @Athos main thread stops and waits for `thread t1` to finish but that doesn't mean that program will stop execution of `thread t2`

Comment: @GauravDhiman i forgot that when thread is created, it automatically enters the queue. That is why thread t2 is executed too.

Comment: @GauravDhiman the test proves that i am right. if i move std::thread t2{...} after t1.join(). it gets deadlock

Answer (score 0):

You have made the wrong assumption that mutexes can be locked and unlocked from different threads.

A mutex locked by one thread cannot be unlocked by another thread. The whole lock/unlock process is per thread.

```
 lock_bar_.unlock();
```

This line in your first function has no meaning. See [ReleaseMutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-releasemutex) in Windows (I guess it works that way in other OSes). It releases the mutex previously locked from the current thread, not from anyother else.

Comment: join waits until a thread is finished. The way you have coded it, no thread waits for another thread. Your problem is not join(), but the way a mutex works.

Comment: mutex fixed, please see the edited program, same question, much thx

Answer (score -1):

the answer is that when std::thread t2{} is created, it enters the queue. that is why t2 is also executed. join() does mean start().

Comment: What queue are you talking about?

Comment: the queue which stores threads that cpu decide which one to call in a certain period